# Using ArcGIS locally with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am currently working on a project in Laravel for which we need to use ArcGIS. The ArcGIS component works as expected when it is loaded from js.arcgis.com, though it is brutally slow (this is likely because the processes we're trying to run are pretty intensive).
I would like to switch to using a local version of ArcGIS instead of loading from the net, but every attempt to do this fails.
I am using Laravel 5.3 and ArcGIS 3.20.

Code that works:
`<script type="text/javascript" src='https://js.arcgis.com/3.20compact/'></script>`

Code that doesn't work:
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/arcgis_js_api/library/3.20/3.20compact/') !!}"></script>`

The page is a .blade.php file, and I have checked that the `asset()` section gets the proper (or at least expected) filepath.

Comment: Make sure you get the expected js code if you take the rendered html, view source, find the script tag and copy its src attribute into a new browser tab.

Comment: I thought I'd checked this, but it turns out I wasn't getting the right js code. Fiddled with the script source a little more and it ended up working. Thanks so much!